# How to install WordPress locally for developing multiple websites

Tags: wordpress

I have installed `WordPress` using **Bitnami** locally, I've developed a website through that.

Now I want to develop second WordPress website (locally). So, do I need to install second Bitnami WordPress or **what** should I do now ?

All I want is to develop new WordPress website.

I'm searching for this for about 2 days, but I am not finding relevant information, may be the words are not correct for what I want to do, please help me

I know the method of installing `XAMPP` and extracting wordpress files in `htdocs`, but since there is some problem in that , that is why I want to go with Bitnami installation.

Here is my **Bitnami**  `Folder`.

**Bitnami** Folder contain another folder, which then contain the following stuff.

When I type `localhost/wordpress` then it loads my site locally, although I don't have any `wordpress` folder that is inside **Bitnami**.
[image]

Thank you every respected out there.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  there are 2 different ways of having more than one site locally, below is the easier way, it only takes 2-3 mins to set up. The other one, is to build up a second website under **the same wordpress folder** as your first website. I used both before, but now I recommend the first one, it saves time and runs faster.

Do you have the /htdocs file folder locally? like this?

[image: htdocs should be under your local server folder]

And you have a **wordpress.zip** file some where right?

[image: just open zip file and drag a whold wordpress folder out]

Now you can directly unzip this wordpress.zip file into htdocs folder,like this,
[image: rename the folder to whatever you like]

After you rename the wordpress folder, to whatever it needs to be,

visit: **localhost/thisRenamedFolder** from your browswer as you did with the other site and complete the installation

Is this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: hi @hong cai , thanks for your reply
well, I'm using Bitnami, which is like an installer for WordPress, as I mentioned I'm not using xampp because with xampp I'm facing some problem

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question, I've updated it

Comment: hi then you should find out where the "htdocs"for binami,more or less the same as xampp/wamp, and create another folder named let say **"wordpress2"** ,and visit **"localhost/wordpress2"**, see the link below from binami community, and try looking into:**C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs** [link](https://community.bitnami.com/t/where-did-bitnami-put-the-wordpress-folder-when-i-installed-it/59002)

Comment: and if you happen to not find the wordpress filefolder, there is another way, try use Windows search tool and find  loation of **"wp-config.php"**, and that's where the **wordpress** folder is, then just unzip another wordpress parallel to this one

Comment: Thanks for the link you've provided, but here is the thing :
I don't have even XAMPP,how could I look into `C:\xampp\apps\wordpress\htdocs` , I have just Bitnami installed.
However I have this directory in Bitnami folder like this :
`C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.2-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs`
and in `htdocs` I've wordpress files, like wp-admin,content, includes etc

Comment: So I think, when I type `localhost/wordpress` it loads the my site from this directory `C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.2-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs`.

So I done something like this :
I made new `folder`  with name site in `C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.2-0\apps\wordpress\htdocs\`
I downloaded new Wordpress and extract that into the new made folder `site`.

Then when I type `localhost/site`, it says **page not found**

Comment: **the key** is to find where the **first wp-config.php** file folder is, because that's where **binami** reads your wordpress file, and just set up another one parallel to the first one.

Comment: u are almost there:)), where are **wp-admin,wp-content** are? in **apps/wordpress/htdocs**? or just under **apps/wordpress/**??, it's because you didn't set up a separate folder for each wordpress, so the**binami** defaultly think where the wp-config.php file is, where the wordpress is. so I suggest, you create a file folder name: wordpress1 in the same folder as **wp-config.php** , put all your first **wp-content,wp-config.php,everything** into this file folder, then try: localhost/wordpress/wordpress1, if this link is accessable, it means things are right

Comment: or **localhost/wordpress1**, just try, it won't be far from near this path

Comment: respected thank you so much for your help, I uninstall Bitnami and install XAMPP, now that is okay, with Bitnami the experience wasn't good, once again thanks for the help